# Laravel Homestead 403 Error

Tags: php, laravel, http-status-code-403

I am getting an error on Laravel Homstead which stated the 403 forbidden error, I cannot seem to see what is wrong in the .yaml file. I am using OSX if that helps. Below is my .yaml file for assistance.

```
    ---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: /Users/jordanbarber/vagrant/laravel/projects/mysite/html/vAMSYS
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/base/public

databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 93000
#       to: 9300
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

Comment: Are you getting the error when trying to create / boot the virtual machine, or once its booted and you try to access your site?

Comment: once it's booted and trying to access the site.

Comment: I have changed the path folder map to /Users/jordanbarber/vagrant/laravel/projects/vAMSYS and now i get a no input file specified error.

Answer (score 1):

Continue from " so, what would that directory be? " If you're using windows, go to you root folder and type "cmd" in the path at the top, after that run

```
vagrant reload
```

Comment: I'm using OSX sadly.

Answer (score 1):

Your folder might be wrong.

Open a terminal window in your project directory and enter

```
pwd
```

This prints the working directory, change the working directory in your yaml file.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also edit your /etc/hosts file to include:

```
192.168.10.10  homestead.app
```

Then run

```
vagrant reload --provision
```

Comment: Did you also run the vagrant command after editing homestead's yaml file?

Comment: as in just the vagrant command? However, i can ssh into the server fine, so the problem is viewing it on the browser.

Comment: Yes, just the vagrant command from your Homestead directory.  (Not in ssh)

Comment: so, what would that directory be?

Comment: Wherever you installed Homestead.  For me its ~/Homestead7

Comment: Its the same directory where you run vagrant ssh

Comment: Then the folder and/or site paths in homestead's yaml file are wrong.  Once you fix it, run the reload command again.